# Pass a lot of parameters (ajax, asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-ajax

I want to pass some parameters via ajax function. I was able to pass the string list or 2 parameters (int type). I'm having trouble passing a list and an int parameter. Ultimately, there may be even more parameters than two.

My example:

.cs file:

```
public string AddListElement(int secId, List<string> fieldsList)
{
//code...
return "a";
}
```

.cshtml file:

```
<script>
    function AddElement(idSection) { 
        var stringArray = new Array();
        stringArray[0] = "item1";
        stringArray[1] = "item2";
        stringArray[2] = "item3";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/BK/User/AddListElement",
            data: {
                secId: idSection,
                fieldsList: stringArray,
            },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
        }).fail(function () {
            //code...
        }).done(function (data) {
            //code...
        });
    }
</script>

//other code...

<div class="form-group main-center2 col-8 mt-2">
    <a class="btn btn-success btn btn-block" onclick="AddElement(@Model.Section[i].Id);" href="#">
        Dodaj
    </a>
</div>
```

In this case, idSec is well passed but the list is null. I was able to pass it well by passing the idSec in the Url and the list like this. But in my opinion it's not the best solution, especially if I want more parameters, e.g. 2 lists and 3 int parameters.

How can I pass multiple parameters like this? Assuming that the parameters are different: int, string, list.
I read similar topics but no way worked for me.

PS.

Comment: @Fildor yes, this change didn't help ;\

Comment: Is public string `AddListElement(int secId, List<string> fieldsList)` your controller method?

Comment: yes, its typo. A the moment I edit my post. And second question: yes, its controller method

Comment: You should also include any attributes on your controller method (e.g. `Route` or `HttpPost`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to receive JSON content from body is define a model according to the attributes of JSON, like your situation, you can define this:

```cs
public class ReceiveData
{
    public int secId { get; set; }
    public List <string > fieldsList { get; set; }
}
```

And the controller:

```cs
public string AddListElement(ReceiveData data)
{
//code...
return "a";
}
```

But if you do not want to define a extra model, you can use a `Dictionary<string, object>` to hold all the data you want to receive from POST:

```cs
public string AddListElement(Dictionary<string, object> keyValuePairs)
{
    //code...
    return "a";
}
```

**Only one parameter per action may be bound from body**

Comment: What would the function in the cshtml file look like then? My above won't work. "Only one parameter per action may be bound from body" - when I sent two int it worked: 
public string AddListElement(int a, int b)...

and cshtml file then look like:
...
            data: {
                secId = idSection,
                fieldId: ifField,
            },

Comment: @Daniel  `=` is invalid after a property name, did you really use a `=`?

Comment: my mistake as I reduced the example here. It should be ":" which does not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Controller methods map a single parameter to the request body; you can use `[FromBody]` (a parameter attribute) to specify which one ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)):

> When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a JSON object).
>
> At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. So this will not work:
>
> ```cs
> // Caution: Will not work!    
> public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
> ```

In your case, create a DTO that models the JSON object you send:

```cs
class ListElementDto {
    public int SecId { get; set; }
    public List<string> FieldsList { get; set; }
}

public string AddListElement([FromBody] ListElementDto model)
{
    //code...
    return "a";
}
```

**Side-note:** you will want to set the `Content-Type` header in your request to `"application/json"`, and I also recommend running `JSON.stringify` on your `data`. Ajax `dataType` is for telling ajax what to expect as the server response.